# Calculating coordinates of extra balancing mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

[image: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjdKz.jpg)

Hello, I have unbalanced mechanism which center of rotation is not in line with center of its mass and I'm trying to calculate coordinates $x_1$ and $y_1$ of mass that would balance it.

I've tried to use forces and torques - there is centrifugal force and the Torque by it ($M \omega^2 \delta \sin a$, $\sin a = 0$) and Angular Force( $M \varepsilon \delta$ and non zero Torque - ($ M \varepsilon \delta$)

Also, $ \varepsilon $ is Angular Acceleration

So from my calculation:

$$ x_1 = 0 $$
$$ y_1 = \frac{M}{m} \delta $$

But i think the answer is not right and in this case balancing is not that easy.

Please help!

Comment: Does the question explain what $\varepsilon$ is? It's unclear from the diagram.

Comment: Just to be clear, we have a circular disk in the x-y plane, with axis of rotation (not through the centre)  along the z-axis, and a balancing mass somewhere in the x-y plane, right?

Comment: @wyphan - ε is angular acceleration, I've added it to post

Comment: @DJohnM, you are perfectly right.

Comment: With the information given you can only do a static balance, where the combined center of mass falls on the rotation axis. If you had more information on the mass moment of inertia of the system, then you can place two masses to balance out of plane torques also.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo force components are:

$$\vec{F}_c=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -m \left( -{\omega}^{2}x-\epsilon\,y-2\,
\omega\,{\dot y} \right) \\ -m \left( -{\omega}^{2}y
+\epsilon\,x+2\,\omega\,{\dot x} \right) \\ 0
\end {array} \right] 
$$

where $\omega=\int \dot\epsilon\,dt+\omega_0$

pseudo force mass $M$ with $x=0\,,y=-\delta$

$$\vec F_M=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -M\epsilon\,\delta\\ M{
\omega}^{2}\delta\\ 0\end {array} \right]
$$

pseudo force mass $m$ with $x=x_1\,,y=y_1$

$$\vec F_m=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -m \left( {\omega}^{2}x_{{1}}-\epsilon\,y_{{
1}}+2\,\omega\,{\dot x}_{{1}} \right) \\ -m \left( {
\omega}^{2}y_{{1}}+\epsilon\,x_{{1}}+2\,\omega\,{\dot y}_{{1}}
 \right) \\ 0\end {array} \right] 
$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
   \ddot x_1 \\
   \ddot y_1 \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\vec F_m+\vec F_M\tag 1$$

assuming $\dot x_1=0\,,\dot y_1=0\,,\ddot x_1=0\,,\ddot y_1=0~$ and solve eq. (1)
for $x_1\,,y_1~$ you obtain your solution

$$x_1=0\,,~,y_1=\frac{M\,\delta}{m}$$

general case you must solve the ODE's eq. (1),to obtain the solutions $~x(t)\,,y(t)$

Answer (score 0):

Using the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem),
$$ I_\mathrm{disk} = I_{CM} + M d^2 $$
the moment of inertia of the disk about the axis, assuming the mass is distributed uniformly in the disk, is
$$ I_{\mathrm{disk}} = \frac{1}{2} M r^2 + M \delta^2 $$

Let's treat the balancing mass as a point mass.
$$ I_m = m r_1^2 $$
where $r_1$ will follow the following relation:
$$ r_1^2 = x_1^2 + y_1^2 $$

For simplicity, pick $x_1 = 0$. (This doesn't hold if the mass of the disk is not uniformly distributed. Then you'll have to pick $x_1 = - x_\mathrm{CM, ~ disk}$.)

Now, for the mechanism to be balanced, so that the mechanism rotates at constant angular momentum $\omega$, the center of mass of the composite (disk + mass) system has to be located at the axis, that is, we want $r_\mathrm{CM, system} = (0, 0)$. The center of mass of the uniform disk is located at $(0, -\delta)$. Then we can find $y_1$ using the formula for center of mass:
$$ \begin{align}
y_\mathrm{CM, ~ system} &= \frac{ M y_\mathrm{CM, ~ disk} + m y_1}{ M + m } \\
(0) &= \frac{ M (-\delta) + m y_1 }{ M + m } \\
y_1 &= \frac{M}{m} \delta
\end{align} $$

So, OP's answer is already correct.

Comment: Why have you placed the mass "m" a distance "r" from the axis of rotation?

Comment: IMO that's the only way to balance the system. The balancing mass $m$ is attached to the axis (presumably with a massless rod) and will also rotate with angular velocity $\omega$. Btw I just realized the original diagram uses small $r$ for the disk radius, so I just revised the distance of the balancing mass from the axis to $r_1$.

Comment: I've revised the answer, using center of mass instead of angular momentum.

Comment: @wyphan - does your answer change, when Angular acceleration = ε? Added that info to original post also.

Comment: @Kuba-a The beauty of using the center of mass approach is that the answer does not depend on whether the net torque is zero or not.